# Which OS for an IBM X30

Tags: laptop

I have an IBM Thinkpad X30 laptop with these specs:

- P-III 1.2 GHz
- 256 RAM
- 40 GB HD

Currently I run Ubuntu 8.4 on it, but it's to slow.

I need a lightweight OS (Linux or windows) for

- text
- viewing pdf's
- surfing the Internet

Do you have any advice for a laptop with these specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a derivative of Ubuntu called [Xubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/WhatIsUbuntu/xubuntu) that is designed to run on slower computers. [Check it out](http://www.xubuntu.org/)!

> Xubuntu is an official derivative of Ubuntu using the Xfce desktop environment. It is intended for users with less-powerful computers, or those that require a highly efficient desktop environment on faster systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for an older systems. Lucid puppy 528 and wary puppy are varients of [puppy linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/How%20to%20download%20Puppy.htm) that run well on older systems. I believe the best options are [tinycore linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) and damned small linux due to their lower ram requirements - tinycore is only 12mb for a gui build, and you can add software for web browsing and PDF viewing.

If you need a newer distro, you can get [linux mint 12 lxde](http://www.linuxmint.com/release.php?id=17) or [older builds of linux mint with fluxbox](http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php). You could also use an older distribution like the [KateOS 2.1 Livecd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KateOS)

If you need to use a livecd for recovery use [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) or use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php). You can use [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) with Parted Magic, and adjust it to your needs as well

Comment: If you add some links for each OS it would help answer the question, and would make for much better and easier to read answer. :)